# maps markers with input sliders

Tags: json

Let me explain the project a bit. i have a huge list of stores with addresses (longitude and latitude and code client ....).

Now, my problem is, i must be able to filter these markers depending on CodeClient i mean to find the client in google maps based on CodeClient .

Comment: *filter these markers depending on CodeClient* and *find the client in google maps based on CodeClient* what does that mean exactly?

Comment: i mean = for exemple if i put the CodeClient( for exemple 123) in a search box in the map , it wil show me the marker of this client who has this code exactly (the markers who has the code client 123) . @MrUpsidown

Comment: Do you need something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329280/5140781 ?

Comment: @xomena , my problem is, users must be able to filter these markers depending on one thing: CodeClient. So to be more specific. If the user sets the CodeClient in the input slider it is supposed to only show the client (the owner of the CodeClient who we put in the slider) 
Like this ; CodeClient = 12345 , so when we click on the button it should see only the marker of this client , i mean the markers who refer to the place of this client. I hope my answer was clear, thank you

Comment: @xomena any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is similar to the answer I mentioned before. You should add an input for code of client and a search button. In the function where you create markers add a property 'code' for each marker `marker.code = CodeClient;`. When you click search button it executes the `filterByCode()` function. If you pass empty value it restores all markers.

Have a look at modified code

```js
// necessary variables
var map;
var infoWindow;
var markersData = [];
var markerCluster;
var markerArray = []; //create a global array to store markers

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32, -6),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // create MarkerClusterer, markersArray is not populated yet
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  // a new Info Window is created
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });
  // Finally displayMarkers() function is called to begin the markers creation
  displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


// This function will iterate over markersData array
// creating markers with createMarker function
function displayMarkers() {

  // this variable sets the map bounds according to markers position
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // for loop traverses markersData array calling createMarker function for each marker 
  $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abdelhakimsalama/358669eda44d8d221bf58c629402c40b/raw/bae93c852669a35f0e7053e9f8d068841ddf146a/get_data_google_api", function(response) {
    markersData = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].Latitude, markersData[i].Longitude);
      var Route = markersData[i].Route;
      var Secteur = markersData[i].Secteur;
      var Agence = markersData[i].Agence;
      var CodeClient = markersData[i].CodeClient;
      var PrecisionGPS = markersData[i].PrecisionGPS;
      var Latitude = markersData[i].Latitude;
      var Longitude = markersData[i].Longitude;
      var BarCode = markersData[i].BarCode;
      var PrenomClient = markersData[i].PrenomClient;
      var NumAdresse = markersData[i].NumAdresse;
      var Tel = markersData[i].Tel;
      var Whatsapp = markersData[i].Whatsapp;
      var NbrFrigo = markersData[i].NbrFrigo;
      var OpenAm = markersData[i].OpenAm;
      var CloseAm = markersData[i].CloseAm;
      var OpenPm = markersData[i].OpenPm;
      var ClosePm = markersData[i].ClosePm;
      var OpenAmVen = markersData[i].OpenAmVen;
      var CloseAmVen = markersData[i].CloseAmVen;
      var OpenPmVen = markersData[i].OpenPmVen;
      var ClosePmVen = markersData[i].ClosePmVen;
      var OpenAmDim = markersData[i].OpenAmDim;
      var CloseAmDim = markersData[i].CloseAmDim;
      var OpenPmDim = markersData[i].OpenPmDim;
      var ClosePmDim = markersData[i].ClosePmDim;
      var IMEI = markersData[i].IMEI;
      var Date_Added = markersData[i].Date_Added;

      createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added);

      // marker position is added to bounds variable
      bounds.extend(latlng);
    }
    // Finally the bounds variable is used to set the map bounds
    // with fitBounds() function
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}


// This function creates each marker and it sets their Info Window content
function createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: CodeClient
  });
  
  marker.code = CodeClient;

  markerArray.push(marker); //push local var marker into global array
  // add marker to the MarkerClusterer
  markerCluster.addMarker(marker);

  // This event expects a click on a marker
  // When this event is fired the Info Window content is created
  // and the Info Window is opened.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    var dicoFrigosDetails = {};


    var HTMLtext = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(dicoFrigosDetails).length / 4; i++) {
      HTMLtext += '';
    }
    // Creating the content to be inserted in the infowindow
    var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
      '<div class="iw_title">Code Client : ' + CodeClient +
      '</div>' + '<div class="iw_content">Précision : ' + PrecisionGPS +
      '<br />Latitude : ' + Latitude +
      '<br />Longitude : ' + Longitude +
      '<br />Route : ' + Route +
      '<br />Secteur : ' + Secteur +
      '<br />Agence : ' + Agence +
      '<br />Code-barres : ' + BarCode +
      '<br />prenom de Client : ' + PrenomClient +
      //'<br />nom Complet de Client : ' + PrenomClient + ' ' + NomClient +
      '<br />Num Adresse : ' + NumAdresse +
      '<br />Téléphone : ' + Tel +
      '<br />Whatsapp : ' + Whatsapp +
      '<br />Nbr Frigos : ' + NbrFrigo + HTMLtext +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin : ' + OpenAm +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin : ' + CloseAm +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi : ' + OpenPm +
      '<br />Fermeture Après-midi : ' + ClosePm +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin Ven : ' + OpenAmVen +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin Ven : ' + CloseAmVen +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi Ven: ' + OpenPmVen +
      '<br />Fermeture après-midi Ven: ' + ClosePmVen +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin Dim : ' + OpenAmDim +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin Dim : ' + CloseAmDim +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi Dim : ' + OpenPmDim +
      '<br />Fermeture après-midi Dim : ' + ClosePmDim +
      '<br />IMEI : ' + IMEI +
      '<br />Date Passage : ' + Date_Added +
      '</div>';

    // including content to the Info Window.
    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    // opening the Info Window in the current map and at the current marker location.
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function filterByCode() {
    var code = document.getElementById("code-client").value;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    if (code) {
        markerArray.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });

        var filtered = markerArray.filter(function(marker) {
          return marker.code === code;
        }); 
    
        if (filtered && filtered.length) {
          filtered.forEach(function(marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        
          markerCluster.addMarkers(filtered);
          markerCluster.redraw();
          
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          
       }
    } else {
        markerArray.forEach(function(marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
        
        markerCluster.addMarkers(markerArray);
        markerCluster.redraw();    
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

#iw_container .iw_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.iw_content {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>InnoTech - Map - Server</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="search-code-container">
  <input id="code-client" title="Enter code" type="text" placeholder="Enter code (E.g. 511557)" value=""/>
  <input id="code-client-btn" type="button" value="Search" onclick="filterByCode()" />
</div> 
<div id="map-canvas" />
```

I hope this helps!